# How to execute a cmd file in a loop with a delay between each iteration?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a cmd file 'D:\ProgramFiles\test.cmd'.

I want to write a script which would execute this test.cmd in a loop *n* times, also, after each execution, I want a delay/timeout of 5 seconds.

How should I go about this?

Comment: Check out the `for /L` and `timeout` commands.

Answer (score 2):

The `timeout` command is not always available. For example when executing a batch file on a build server like Jenkins or when running on an older version of Windows. However, there is a way that will always work:

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR %%i IN (1,1,5) do (
    CALL "D:\ProgramFiles\test.cmd"
    ping 127.255.255.255 -n 1 -w 5000> nul
)
```

Here we are using the ping command. `ping 127.255.255.255 -n 1 -w 5000> nul` will ping the IP address 127.255.255.255. This address won't be reachable but `-w 5000` will make the command "wait" for 5000ms = 5s for a response. The only limitation is that you can't go below 500 ms with this method. Any number below 500 will result in a delay of 500 ms.

You can use `ping -n 6 localhost>nul` as well. This will repeat the ping six times. Notice that you will need 6 repetitions to achieve a delay of 5 seconds as the first ping will be launched immediately so six pings mean 5 seconds delay. Don't fall victim to the famous "[fencepost error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error)"

For further information check [this](https://ss64.com/nt/timeout.html) website.

Comment: `ping 127.0.0.1 -n 1 -w 5000` will NOT cause any delay, because `127.0.0.1` always responds immediately to the ping, so no amount of timeout with `-w` has any effect. for this to work you have to use an ip address that will never responds to the ping then you can use any number with `-w` to make the delay. You can use the loopback broadcast address which will never responds. `127.255.255.255`

Answer (score 1):

a For loop is what you want. in this instance, we tell it to start counting by 1, steps of 1, end at 5, which means you will be running 5 loops. For more on the `for` run from cmd.exe `for /?`

Timeout, depends on your OS version. Older OS's does not have it, then perhaps look at the older version called `sleep` or alternatively use the command `ping` with a count of timeout you want, +1. `timeout` On some Windows versions you do not like the `/t` and therefore can be used without it. i.e `timeout 5`

```
@echo off
for %%i in (1,1,5) do (
    echo We do something here..
    timeout /t 5
)
```

To learn about Windows cmd/batch commands, and how to use them in a batch files you can open `cmd` and type `help` which will list loads of commands. each of them can then be run followed by the `/?` switch to get full help on each command.

Answer (score 0):

Example (n = 200):

```
FOR /L %%A IN (1,1,200) DO (
  D:/ProgramFiles/test.cmd
  timeout /t 5
)
```

Comment: don't know, but in comparison with the other answer with +1, it lacks some explanation. You should `call D:/ProgramFiles/test.cmd` (test with an additional line `echo Done.` after the loop (with and without `call`) to see why)

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I don't understand what you mean by "i like short word".